# Could spin waves be the cause of the pseudogap?

Tags: superconductivity

Could spin waves be the cause of the [pseudogap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudogap) and therefore be able to nudge the electrons in cuprate superconductors in a similar way that phonons (vibration waves) nudge electron in conventional superconductors?